# How do I use RVM to run Ruby files in a particular version?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to use RVM to run programs in a particular version. Running this script `puts RUBY_VERSION`, outputs `1.8.7`:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

The following command shows different versions of Ruby installed:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

How do I run my Ruby script in ruby-1.9.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.2-p290 do ruby --version
```

That said, it looks like your system Ruby has a higher path precedence than RVM. You might try doing an RVM reinstall or uninstalling your system Ruby to make sure that your system paths are managed properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you change `PATH`. Usually RVM detects and fixes it when is sourced and when Ruby is used. Most likely you still managed to set PATH after RVM was sourced.

The easiest way to fix it is to use Ruby again:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

I also opened a [ticket](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2044) to remind myself to add a warning for this problem.